# Find and copy the first row if cell in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have ~5000 rows with 5 to 45 columns and in column E are unique or duplicate values. Always the first row that has duplicate must be copied to sheet 2. SO if i have in E2 to E10 the same value, copy row 2 in sheet 2 .
I must copy the values of the row because there are formulas and i don't want to delete the rows just copy them in sheet 2.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowcheck = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For n1 = 1 To LastRowcheck
            If .Cells(n1, 5).Value = Cells(n1 + 1, 5).Value Then
               .Rows(n1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(n1)

            End If
        Next n1

        If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, how to copy the first row that has in column E a value that exist in other rows

Comment: Do you only want rows that have duplicated values copied? Or do you want all values copied, but ignoring duplicates (so also copying non-duplicate values)?

Comment: Also, is your data sorted so that all duplicates will be next to each other?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are having? Is the problem that the duplicates (in column E) are not on adjacent rows - meaning your code does not identify these duplicated?

Comment: Are you just after all unique values, or only duplicates? To get all unique Just copy the entire data set then remove duplicates based on col E (can be done through vba). The remove duplicate function always leaves the first value.